# sql query adding column values

Tags: sql

I want to add two columns values of my table and sort it in descending order. E.g:

```
int_id   int_test_one  int_test_2
 1           25           13    
 2           12           45    
 3           25           15
```

Considering the table above, I want a SQL query which give me the result like below:

```
   int_id  sum(int_test_one,int_test_two)
    2              57
    3              40   
    1              38
```

Is there any sql query to do this?

Comment: There is a nearest nice answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37466003/3835843

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is not built in function for this kind of horizontal aggregation, you can just do...

```
SELECT INT_ID, INT_TEST_ONE + INT_TEST_TWO AS SUM FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try what you describe? This works:

```
SELECT int_id , ( int_test_one + int_test_two ) as s FROM mytable ORDER BY s DESC
```

You can ommit the "as" keyword if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    int_id, 
    (int_test_one + int_test_two) AS [Total] 
FROM 
    mytable 
ORDER BY 
    [Total] DESC
```