# add to a value in a row in an SQL table

Tags: sql, addition, cumulative-sum

This should be a simple question and please forgive me if it is so simple that I look like a dunce.

How do I take a number, say 6, and add it to a row that has a value, say 4, so that the row now has a value of 10?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql query adding column values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220453/sql-query-adding-column-values)

Answer (score 2):

Use `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET columnName = columnName + 6
WHERE <filtering conditions>
```